# javascript - how to "concatinate" a property

Tags: javascript, properties, three.js

I am retrieving values from json for a three.js scene.

Now I would like to convert data like "position.x : 1" to object[ position ] [ x ] = 1.

object [ key ] = value does not work. Obviously as it makes it object[ position.x ] = 1.

How would I do that or how is this kind of procedure called ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
var string = "position.x : 1";
var split = string.split(/\.|\:/);   // split the strig into an array by '.' and ':'
var obj = {};                        // result object

function getObject(split) {
   obj[split[0].trim()] = {};
   obj[split[0].trim()][split[1].trim()] = split[2].trim();
}

getObject(split);                    // call the function and pass the array of values

console.log( obj );                  // print the whole result object
console.log( obj['position']['x'] ); // print obj['position']['x']
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in function for that.

But there are plenty of third-party modules available for this task.

For example, you could use [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/)'s `_.set`. The docs are [here](https://lodash.com/docs#set) and you can also use it stand-alone without adding the full `lodash` package, by using the [`lodash.set`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.set) package instead.

Example, from the docs:

```js
var object = { 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c': 3 } }] };

_.set(object, 'a[0].b.c', 4);
console.log(object.a[0].b.c);
// => 4

_.set(object, ['x', '0', 'y', 'z'], 5);
console.log(object.x[0].y.z);
// => 5
```

If you don't like `_.set`, there are [many](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dot-prop) [other](https://www.npmjs.com/package/set-value) [options](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-path) [too](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dot-object).

Comment: I think your answer was better before the edit. That own-rolled version has potential prototype pollution problems, has a time complexity problem, and can cause a stack overflow.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the prototype pollution and time complexity? Is the latter about the repeated `slice`? Regarding stack overflow it's of course true but we'd have to have an insanely long property path, I'm trading that chance for simplicity.

Comment: This version also doesn't check for existence of sub-paths obviously, so yes I could do for example `set(something, { length: 123 }, x)` or `set(something, { slice: 'oh no' }, x)` and such and it would crash, but it would also crash on `set(something, 'nonexisting.abc', x)` at the moment

Comment: Anyway, I removed it again (instead you can see it in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/CherryDT/68b1d7cad14b55b464b992f2a19f8eb4)) since the only reason I added it in the first place was to show an example implementation in the post itself as well instead of just linking to packages. I would still be interested in your answers though.

Comment: Moved it here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/240857/function-to-set-nested-property-by-dot-path-like-set

Comment: @Ry- (In case you didn't get pinged)

Comment: @ CherryDT  Thank you very much for your fast and extensive answer.
@ Ivan86 I vote your answer because it is more simplistc and vanilla.

Comment: @Paul in case you are interested, [this was my simplistic vanilla solution](https://gist.github.com/CherryDT/68b1d7cad14b55b464b992f2a19f8eb4). I just removed it because there were some flaws pointed out that the more extensive solutions of those libraries didn't have.

Comment: @CherryDT Yes I am. This looks smart and very elegant. 
I give you another double_thumb_up for this.
Keep up your excellent and generous work.

Comment: @CherryDT In fact I split the string by ".", ran it through a for loop and build a string which I evaled at the end. So I had no issues with the number of possible segments...
I know some people will grab their stones right now.... ;)